# incrementing and transfering to Holders

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan

Hallo guys Every time i try to sell and distrbute to Holders i get reverted
transaction Hash : 0x511a62a40ac43fef117bba410bb375eb67e5ae964c29f3f2d400c04fb0a79562

the Debug shows fail in the Sell token Function dont know what wrong here

```
    address[] private holders;
    function transferToHolders(uint256 valueToDistribute) payable public {
    uint256 numHolders = holders.length;
    if (numHolders <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    uint256 portion = valueToDistribute / numHolders;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < holders.length; i++) {
        require(portion > 0);
        transferFrom(msg.sender, holders[i], portion);
    }
}

function incrementHolders (address payable holder) public {
    holders.push (holder);
}
function forwardFunds(uint256 value) public payable {
    require(msg.sender == _wallet, "no way!");
    _wallet.transfer(value);
}
   function sellTokens() public payable {
    require(publicBuyActivated == true, "public Sell not lunched yet");
    require(_token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= msg.value, "you dont have enought tokens");

    address payable beneficiary = msg.sender;
    uint256 holdersAmount,

    uint256 userAmount) = getSellPercents(msg.value);

    if (userAmount < msg.value) {

        _token.transferToHolders(holdersAmount);
        
    }
    beneficiary.transfer(userAmount);
}
```

whenever i comment this line the sell work but nothing diturbuted to the holders

```
        _token.transferToHolders(holdersAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to change `transferFrom(msg.sender, holders[i], portion)` to `_token.transferFrom(msg.sender, holders[i], portion)`.
2. In order for transferForm to work, the msg.sender should have first of all called `_token.approve(yourContractAddress, valueToDistribute)`. If you haven't done this, it should be called before you can call `transferToHolders`.

Comment: thanks i tried but still not working do you have other suggestions ??

Comment: I'll be able to help more if you write exactly what you are doing now and what exactly is failing with what message.

Comment: i would like to send you the whole contract on private but i dont know how to reach you if u can provide me with your email it would be great and i would be pleased and greatful for your support